# In CCXT library for FTX exchange, is it possible to cancel all STOP order instead of cancelling all STOP and TAKE PROFIT and TRAILING STOP order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithmic-trading, ccxt

When using CCXT and in FTX exchange, I am able to cancel all conditional trade with the following code:

```
exchange.cancel_all_orders(symbol,params={'conditionalOrdersOnly': False})
```

But is it possible to cancel all STOP order instead of cancelling all STOP and TAKE PROFIT and TRAILING STOP order? or the only way is to use the cancel_order() function together with the order ID argument?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. There's no mention of this feature in the FTX api docs or CCXT docs:
https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#orders
https://docs.ftx.com/#cancel-order

See also the CCXT/FTX source for confirmation:
https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/ftx.py#L1623

The CCXT team did a complete integration with FTX so consider asking them here: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues

FWIW I'm implementing FTX through CCXT also and store all orders in another DB with some added properties - to make things easier when handling orders. Either way you'll have to fetch existing orders, parse out ids then cancel them individually to cancel only stop orders.